# Weirdness in Pandas.Series.map function for a TimeStamp series

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Something weird is happening in applying a function on a panda.Series

```
In [508]: id = lambda x : x
In [509]: tt = lambda x : type(x)
In [510]: timeSeries
Out[510]: 
0   1900-01-01 20:11:49.075690
1   1900-01-01 20:11:49.082546
2   1900-01-01 20:11:52.535287
3   1900-01-01 20:11:52.535372
4   1900-01-01 20:11:52.535528
Name: timeSeries

In [511]: timeSeries.map(id)
Out[511]: 
0    1969-12-06 172:11:49.075690
1    1969-12-06 172:11:49.082546
2    1969-12-06 172:11:52.535287
3    1969-12-06 172:11:52.535372
4    1969-12-06 172:11:52.535528
Name: timeSeries
```

Here the timestamps have changed by applying the id function
The hour in the new time is incorrect.
More: the type is also changed

```
In [513]: type(timeSeries[0])
Out[513]: pandas.lib.Timestamp

In [512]: timeSeries.map(tt)
Out[512]: 
0    <type 'numpy.datetime64'>
1    <type 'numpy.datetime64'>
2    <type 'numpy.datetime64'>
3    <type 'numpy.datetime64'>
4    <type 'numpy.datetime64'>
Name: timeSeries
```

I think type change is fine as long as the timestamp they map to is preserved

```
In [515]: np.datetime64(timeSeries[0])
Out[515]: 1900-01-01 20:11:49.075690
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here?
I want to do a map with a customized function where I'm expecting pandas.lib.Timestamp type.
or either if there is a way to convert the np.datetime64 to a valid time.

Edit: Following works to cast the np.datetime64 back to Timestamp. Still the above is weird.

```
In [528]: pd.lib.Timestamp(time2[0])
Out[528]: <Timestamp: 1900-01-01 20:11:49.075690>
In [529]: time2[0]
Out[529]: 1969-12-06 172:11:49.075690
```

My guess is it is about internal formatting difference between np.datetime64 vs pandas.lib.Timestamp??

Comment: I think this was fixed in 10.1 https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2699